# 'nested' template `>>` issue is solved. What about `<::`?

Tags: c++, token, c++11, digraphs

C++0x addresses the issue of consecutive closing angle brackets in template-id's, like in 
`vector<vector<int>>`. No space is required between `> >` any more. Does C++0x address the issue of `<::` like in `vector<::MyType>` ? Is the space between `<` and `::` still required?

***Edit:*** I mean by the wording of the standard (draft). Many compilers cope with that for a long time now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that space is still required currently. But US [National Body comment 15](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1104) requested this to be removed, and it looks like the proposed resolution will be incorporated (since it's "ready").